# Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset

Tags: ssl-certificate, keycloak

I am facing an issue while connecting to one login. please help me

2022-11-22 08:49:10,491 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-509) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset:144)

Answer (score 0):

I have met such an issue before. It looks like you need to trust the certificate authority of the Identity provider by adding its certificate bundle to your trust store

Comment: Yep, that is most likely the issue